Stylesheet not loaded because of MIME type when linking external CSS
I am getting the error: Refused to apply style from ‘...’ because its MIME type (‘text/html’) is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
I believe this error occurs because I have a line in my html which looks like:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/98.css" />
Here is the beginning of the HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/98.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
....

It seems there is an error with linking 98.css. I have already looked at many solutions, but they are well beyond my expertise, which solution would you recommend in this case?

You can't fix that from your end (unless you wanted to proxy the request), the owner of unpkg.com would need to fix this.

Not even if I would manage to import it locally?

Yes, sure, when you serve it from your own system, then you are in control of the response headers. Just thought you wanted to explicitly use such a CDN.
